# SSRS: Refresh one dataset not the entire report

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have added multiple charts on one report and each one is dependent on other one. I have used action->Go To Report to refresh another chart on click of the current chart. But the issue is that its refreshing all the charts/datasets on the current report. I just want to refresh one chart and preserve the value/data of others.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Rishi, but this is not possible with a simple SSRS dashboard, just using the SSRS designer.

There are a few ways to achieve this result with a lot of effort, but each one is essentially coding a master webpage that displays multiple SSRS reports in separate containers on the same page. Then you use server-side ASPX code, or client-side javascript code to interact with the SSRS apis and pass parameters and reload the report(s) that you wish.

Here is one [demo site](http://www.quasarinc.com/demo/dashboards) that using javascript on a SharePoint, PerformancePoint Dashboard to achieve the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel. However, I managed to do this by using parameters on the master report and then reassign the values when any of the bar action takes place. So, this helped me to retain the position of all the bars and make the changes for those which is required.

Now, I have one more question: How can we show a horizontal scroll bar for a graph if the graph is having a lot of data. Eg: If there are 50 bars then by default show only 10 and then scroll to see more or a paging kind of thing. Anyone will work for me.